# Regarding solenoid valve

Tags: arduino, relay, solenoid

Can I only use one 12V DC power supply for two solenoid valves? I got connect the solenoid valves with a 5V 4 channel relay module with arduino as my microcontroller. Each of the solenoid valve is 12V, 2A. The power supply i using is 12V 2A, and i also got connect each valve with 1N4001 Rectifier Diode.

Comment: yes you can, if the power supply is able to source the required current

Comment: The power supply i using is 12V 2A, and i also got connect each valve with 1N4001 Rectifier Diode, is it enough to support the two solenoid valves?

Comment: "Both the solenoid valve is 12V, 2A." Does that mean each valve is rated at 2A or both of them together?

Comment: Each of them are rated as 12V, 2A. Not add together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each solenoid requires 2 A.
- Your power supply is rated for 2 A.
- You can power one solenoid valve at a time.
- You would need a 4 A supply to power both of your solenoids.
- The diodes won't make an extra 2 A appear out of nowhere.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNzIuL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Snubber diodes. You can still only power one 2 A solenoid from a 2 A supply.*

The diodes should be connected as shown. Normally they don't conduct but when the relay contacts open they provide a decay path for the current and protect the relay contacts from arcing damage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgmnlZ.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. As suggested by @SpehroPefhany, this arrangement ensures that only one solenoid can be energised at a time with SV1 getting precedence.*

Comment: +1 OP could interlock one channel through the N.C. contact to prevent both being powered at once.

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Comment: Do you mean power supply should be 12V 4A?

Comment: @Anohana, what part of my answer did you not understand?

Comment: @Transistor, i understand that based on your answer, only one solenoid valve can be powered on at a time. Since i need both the solenoid valves to be powered at the same time, is it the power supply that i used should be 12V and 4A? 

Based on these two sentences:
You can power one solenoid valve at a time.
You would need a 4 A supply to power both of your solenoids.

Comment: Yes, you need a 12 V power supply with a current rating >= 4 A. I thought it was clear.

Comment: @Transistor, okay, I understand already, thank you for you answer for my question. One last question, is it since they connect in parallel, therefore they sharing the same 12 V voltage by power supply?

Comment: Correct. It's like all the devices in a car share the same 12 V supply. Bulbs big and small, wiper motor, fan motor, window-winder motors, central locking, ECU, etc. They're all connected to the battery. Total current is the sum of all the individual currents required by each device that is switched on.

Comment: @Transistor, I'm really grateful and appreciate the solution you provided to me and helping me understand.

Comment: Good! Don't forget to accept the answer to mark the question solved.